# Suggested Edit Stats don't show my stats if I "Reject and Edit" or "Improve Edit"

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, statistics

I did some reviewing in the Suggested Edit queue today. It just so happened that the last one I did I reviewed as "Reject and Edit". I wanted to go back to see what my stats are so far (how many accepts and rejects I have done so far).

I saw this:

[image]

Where are my stats?

It also does not show up if I "Improve Edit"

[image]

<sub>You can click the images to go to the review pages.</sub>

Shouldn't this be consistant with "Approve" and "Reject", which do show my stats? Also, I am sure that before "Edit" would still show your stats.

**Update**

This has been partially implemented, but broken. See [Suggested edits showing the wrong stats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272597/suggested-edits-showing-the-wrong-stats?lq=1). As of July 7th 2015,

> This bug is *still* there. [Antti Haapala](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272597/suggested-edits-showing-the-wrong-stats#comment177300_272597)

Comment: It's possible this is by design, since "improve" and "reject and edit" review actions are not counted in the "approve" and "reject" totals.

Comment: @AirThomas, you would expect with the wording "Reject and Edit", that I rejected the review, so it should count.

Comment: I agree that's a reasonable expectation based on the wording but perhaps not based on history. I think your memory is playing tricks on you with respect to whether "Edit" ever showed up in these stats. (The wording of "Improve" is also inconsistent with that expectation.)

Comment: Right, I have no proof of past edits. I could show you an [older review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4962652), but that right now does not show my stats, and it could be with the way all review pages are rendered.