# Suggested edits showing the wrong stats

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

Yesterday I made [a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272498/suggested-edit-stats-dont-show-my-stats-if-i-reject-and-edit-or-improve-edit) about putting a reviewer's stats when the <kbd>Improve</kbd> or <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd>. That post is about *including the information*. This post is about *the information shown being '0' or being wrong*.

I did some more reviewing of suggested edits and found this:

[image]

This is obviously wrong, and it only seems to be on "Reject and Edit" reviews.

In addition, when I approve an edit, the number of rejects is wrong:

> <sub>These stats are correct</sub>
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>These stats are not correct</sub>
>
> [image]

So what's going on? Was someone starting to fix the issue I reported yesterday, or is this unrelated? It's really hard to yell at robo-reviewers if I can't tell if they are robo-reviewers.

Comment: This post, contrasted with its predecessor, is proof that freehand red circles produce better outcomes on meta than freehand red arrows. Users take note.

Comment: I noticed the same issue myself today (some reviews were right, some had very low counts).

Comment: damn, 800 approved and 6 rejected? You robo-reviewer!!!!! ... Sorry, what was the subject ... ?

Comment: @Theolodis, eh, [I've seen worse](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254678/how-to-educate-folks-on-site-policy-sans-contact#comment20406_254678)

Comment: It was a joke ;) but how are we supposed to disrespect others now, if we can't be sure that the stats are indeed wrong?

Comment: It's weird that this bug received very minimal attention.

Comment: @Omar, I know. It makes it hard to know if I can accurately be mad at other reviewers based on their stats if I know it might not be correct. I would set a bounty on this, I guess the most anyone can do is simple edits to bump it.

Comment: Just noticed the same issue myself.  I made one 'edit and reject' and a plain 'reject' and my stats show I have made a total of 2 rejections (which is about 800 too low)

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I just checked my stats [using this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6363498) and it's forgotten about most of my activity. I'm pretty sure my rejections should outweigh my approvals.

Comment: For some additional reading material / proof, see [this MSE chat discussion](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2774481#2774481) (start at the highlighted, read down a ways)

Comment: I have a query [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/257610?UserId=1043380) to support the weirdness

Comment: This bug is *still* there.

Comment: It looks like it's still there. It looks like on edit suggestions that I reject, but then are approved, it says that I've only rejected one edit.  I've actually rejected 50 edit suggestions.

Comment: [Similar bug report on MSE.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243910/incorrect-suggested-edit-review-count) Also, I found these reports because I just [ran into this bug on crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/14015).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, already upvoted that one. I also have the 5th comment on that post linking back here :)

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, the problem still exists. Almost all the time, my review stats are wrong. Its been showing 224 approved and 11 rejected for a long time now and has not changed even after I've made plenty of reviews after it.

Comment: **Still an issue almost 1 year on**

Comment: Fantastic news! [There is now an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267444/175498) regarding this bug!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One year and six days later, [Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267444/213671) and [Chris Jester-Young](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267480/213671) have fixed this bug!

[image]

To quote the above posts:

> Therefore, the audit result page is using just the "Reject" review
>   result reason, while the regular result page is using just the "Reject
>   and Edit" reason. Arguably, both displays are wrong. They should sum
>   up both the rejections reasons.
>
> I'll check with a developer to see if we can fix this bug.

> This has been fixed and will be deployed in build 3746 for MSE/MSO,
>   and build 2869 for other sites.