# Why are edit suggestion review stats so skewed?

Tags: discussion, bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

e.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7834629

What I see:

[image: 409/10]

This is nonsensical. I would characterize my reviewing as very strict: I probably reject about 1/2 of suggested edits. Go page through my activity if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2891664/radiodef?tab=activity&sort=reviews. It's obvious I've rejected far more than 10.

Note that:

[image: 722]

`722 - 409 = 313`

Why are the review stats completely wrong? What's going on here?

---

Now I'm looking at a different review and I see this:

[image: 414/272]

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7866152

Looks closer to correct, but the math still doesn't add up and some of the reviews still show the other one. If I go to e.g. the first link, the approve number is now 414 too, but the reject number is not updated.

And now the second link shows the wrong number too. I don't see a pattern here.

For my stats:

- 'approved' appears to update correctly within minutes of doing a review and stick.
- 'rejected' appears to alternate randomly.

Comment: Perhaps the effect of deleted posts? They get counted for some things, not for others...

Comment: @Mogsdad That was one of my ideas, but as the second screenshot shows, the number is actually different between review items. Also, 300 deleted posts? And why is approve not lower too? I dunno. I'm pretty baffled.

Comment: @Radiodef - I've wondered that myself; it shows I've reviewed 3800+ suggested edits, but I've only approved 774 of them, and rejected 38 of them.  At one point, I had over 3000+ rejected listed, but that seems to have gotten screwed up earlier this year, or late last year.

Comment: @ChrisF sorry, not what I was suggesting; musefan had asked if someone could open a question they could then edit, which may not work if they can't actually edit.

Comment: Looks to me like the amount of rejected edits is shown different only when all reviewers voted for rejection. Could it be that those 10 are edits you rejected, but were approved by others, and those 272 you and others rejected?

Comment: @Siguza I can't really draw too many conclusions about it, because I've seen the number change in between visits to the same link. There might be multiple caches or something, for example.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @Sobrique I don't think so. If caching is involved, it's still a bug. Notice how in the second screenshot my approve number is higher. This is because in between taking the screenshots I did more reviews. The approve number updated within minutes, but not the reject number. But again...[can't draw too many conclusions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291689/why-are-edit-suggestion-review-stats-so-skewed?noredirect=1#comment183592_291689).

Comment: @Sobrique There are only two hard problems in computer science. Caching, naming things and off-by-one errors.  This is clearly not the second one, so it must be the first.

Comment: I was going to say that the approve/reject numbers leave out Improve Edit and Reject and Edit entirely, but when I went to check in my history, I found myself listed as having [0 approved and 0 rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7858533). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7858461), however, I'm more plausibly listed with 395/233 out of 921, and those have been consistently increasing as expected for weeks.

Comment: Digging around, it seems this is closely related to [Suggested edits showing the wrong stats](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272597)

Comment: I see 432/10 for you at both of those links.

Comment: It's been busted for quite a while. I found myself bemoaning someone for only having one edit rejection. Turns out they had hundreds. It currently shows me as `has approved 335 edit suggestions and rejected 2 edit suggestions` whereas I've over 1000 edit reviews, and the majority are rejections.