# Where can I find suggested edit review stats?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

Since it [seems established](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272597/suggested-edits-showing-the-wrong-stats) that the suggested edit review queue will [report the wrong stats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291689/why-are-edit-suggestion-review-stats-so-skewed) for my reviews, where can I find the stats on my reviews? When I look at a previously approved edit, I get:

> Quincunx has approved 129 edit suggestions and rejected 2 edit suggestions

But on a previously rejected edit:

> Quincunx has approved 129 edit suggestions and rejected 115 edit suggestions

Which adds up to 244, but I've done 249 reviews. How can I tell what reviews I've done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really is [an SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/140194/suggested-edit-review-stats) for everything. Credit goes to [juergen d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575376/juergen-d).

```sql
declare @userid int = ##userid##

select total
    ,approved
    ,round(cast(approved * 100 as float) / total, 1) approvedpercentage
    ,rejected
    ,round(cast(rejected * 100 as float) / total, 1) rejectedpercentage
from (
    select count(case when votetypeid = 2 then 1 end) approved
        ,count(case when votetypeid = 3 then 1 end) rejected
        ,count(votetypeid) total
    from suggestededitvotes
    where userid = @userid
    ) as grouped;
```