# Am I rejecting too many edits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

In regards to reviewing in the suggested edit queue, I seem to be rejecting a lot more edits than most people. I have rejected about the same number of edits as I have approved. Is this a problem?

I tend to reject edits that claim to "improve formatting" but simply change only *part* of the code-formatting, or claim to "improve formatting" but make one tiny little change that doesn't conflict with the author's intent, but doesn't really add anything to the post. However, when I go back later and look at the reviews I've made, it looks like I'm rejecting a lot of edits that other people are approving. Am I perhaps too strict with rejecting?

I do skip most of the posts I think are on the borderline.

Comment: Given my experience with suggested edits, I'd say you might possibly be _approving_ too many edits if your approve/reject rate is about 50/50; but you're definitely not rejecting too much. Please don't be swayed by people who approve just about anything and continue rejecting useless, pointless and trivial edits.

Comment: I looked at mine and saw its 504/538.More rejects than accept.But I think it depends on my luck when I review facing more bad edits than good edits.

Comment: There simply *are* more bad edits than good edits, no?

Comment: *I tend to reject edits that claim to "improve formatting" but simply change only part of the code-formatting* Why? On what grounds? If it improves the formatting, even in an incomplete way, this should not be discouraged.

Comment: For the life of me I cannot find my review stats on my profile, but I'm sure I'm rejecting 60-80% of edits.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. Seems I've rejected around two thirds of everything I review. I'm happy with that number.

Comment: regarding rejecting edits about formatting, this related meta is probably of interest: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297820/was-it-ok-that-this-edit-got-approved

Comment: @DavidG Where? Is it a 10k+ feature? I can only seem to find my total number of reviewed edits.

Comment: I got to something like 40 rejections and 5 approvals before I pretty much gave up on reviewing suggested edits.

Comment: I can tell you from my own experience that it is quite frustrating when I improve a post by taking the 80% approach and someone denies that edit because I didn't go for 100%. Needless to say that the missing 20% often take a lot of effort, because of that I try to improve lets say 5 posts by 80% instead of 1 or 2 by 100%

Comment: @Marged If I see a post improved more than about 60%, I usually improve the edit and fix the rest to the best of my ability.

Comment: The average reviewer in Suggested Edits approves almost anything, except for useful edits that touch code at all. Those are often rejected out of hand. So as long as you're not doing either of those, you're better than average!

Comment: @Samurai8: If you go to http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8592186 and click "(more)", you'll see that "Sumurai8 has approved 921 edit suggestions and rejected 1 edit suggestion". (I don't know if there's a more-direct way to find it than that.)

Comment: Since I got the edit privilege, I did two reviews and in both I _improved_ the edits… they weren’t enough improvement for me…

Comment: @ruakh Those stats are [horribly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272597/suggested-edits-showing-the-wrong-stats) [broken](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291689/why-are-edit-suggestion-review-stats-so-skewed).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: OK, but if those are the stats that this entire discussion is about, then why are you directing that comment at me specifically?

Comment: @ruakh The OP asked a question about [finding reliable review stats](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297816/176646) a few minutes before they asked this question, so I assume they have a rough idea of how many edits they reject, regardless of what the stats say. Also, those stats are not what the entire discussion is about; the OP says, "when I go back later and look at the reviews I've made, it looks like I'm rejecting a lot of edits that other people are approving."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: OK, fair enough, but what I'm saying is -- a *lot* of people in this discussion seem to be using those stats. That includes the accepted answer. If you think your comment is important enough to be worth pointing out (and I'd agree), then you should post a comment in a more higher-visibility way, rather than burying it as a low-context reply to my side-comment.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You should approve if it improves the post, even if it is just a little bit. The "Too minor" rejection reason was removed for a reason.

You should only reject if the edit makes no improvement at all, is too opinionated (eg change one perfectly valid code formatting for a different one) or actually makes things worse.

To quote [Approve as too minor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039) :

> If it's *really* too minor, reviewers should demonstrate that by providing a not-minor edit. If the reviewer opts to build upon the edit instead of starting over from the current revision, then *it isn't too minor!*

And https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253512/466862:

> **Minor edits be good**
>
> 1. SO is intended to be a top-quality Q&A site, meant not just for the OP, but for posterity. Thanks to search engines, questions and answers
>      become authoritative for the whole Internet.
> 2. Spelling and grammar mistakes, even small ones, make posts more difficult to read, and negatively reflect on their quality as a whole.
> 3. SO has a very large community, who read and re-read many questions multiple times a day.
> 4. There is [no shortage](https://stackoverflow.com/review) of reviewers for suggested edits. (Close Votes on the other hand...)
>
> Together, these reasons are compelling for allowing edits, even small
>   ones.

Comment: This, I think, is the answer here. I think most of us are still used to the 'too minor' edits reason. Most edits are OK-ish, but just don't fix all there is to fix in a post, very often even leaving blatantly obvious problems. We tend to think of these as a bad edit, but this reasoning is now outdated, as indicated in this answer.

Answer (score 30):

I wouldn't sweat it. Last time I looked I was at 50/50 as well. It's fine to have a high standard for suggested edits. You're dealing with users who are essentially still in their learning period. So if you don't instil them with what makes an edit "good" now, they won't get it when they have the freedom to edit without review.

If an edit falls significantly short or is somewhat pointless, feel free to reject it. If it's almost there but not quite, accept but improve. And if that is what you're doing already, don't worry about the ratios. The real problem is reviewers who don't seem to reject a thing.

Answer (score 12):

A lot of suggested edits *are* minor, leaving the post they edit in more or less the same state as before the edit. They only add tags but forget to remove them from the title, or they indent the first code block but forget the second, they "fix grammar" but forget to capitalize "i", and so on.

I flat-out reject those as being no improvement whatsoever. I only do that in the described case, when my initial reaction to spotting such an edit was *"Is that really all you could change?"*. By approving the edit, you'll kick the question to the top of the question list, where the remaining horror will be visible for everyone, everyone can see the minor edit that caused it and will think it's OK to do so, adding yet another minor edit suggestion to fix one of the remaining issues, ad infinitum.

Questions that need a lot of work to make them readable and properly tagged generally aren't the best of questions either. So fix it entirely or leave it alone.

But that's my stance. That being said, I don't like to visit the suggested edits queue. I only act on suggested edits if I see one pending on a question I visit. Usually I also check out the suggestion history of users suggesting such "too minor" edits and flag them if I see a pattern.

I had to dig a bit, as I said I don't do if often. One such example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7564730): it fixes a typo in the title but leaves another and leaves the language "tag" ("in .net"), it indents the pseudocode but leaves the typos that are in there, and the edit adds no capitalization to the question text, leaving it in the same abysmal state it was before, albeit a slight bit different. I was the only one rejecting that edit, and look at the question now. Was it worth the attention, or should the editor have spent their time improving a more worthwile question?

To me, it's all about effort spent and sending a signal about that. By approving edits that leave obvious flaws, you're telling the editor *"This is good, you should do that more often"*.

Comment: Would you perhaps consider "Reject and Edit" (or "Improve and Edit", if the edit did something but not all the things) instead of flatly rejecting?

Comment: By your own words they are improvements, just not complete. As such you should either approve, or use improve and edit to further enhance the quality. Your demands for perfection don't square with the actual established rules, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039 (_"If it's really too minor, reviewers should demonstrate that by providing a not-minor edit. If the reviewer opts to build upon the edit instead of starting over from the current revision, then it isn't too minor!"_)

Comment: @Jeffrey yes, if the post is salvageable, I tend to do that. As for "too minor" not existing: I'm with [Servy on “Too minor” edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site). Not every improvement leaves a positive net result, so not every improvement is a good thing.

Comment: An improvement is by definition a good thing, otherwise it wouldn't be an improvement. Also the post by Servy you link is invalidated by the accepted answer.

Comment: @Mark this and the linked question are discussion questions. I don't agree with the accepted answer there and am giving my opinion on the case here. Let's not dive into semantics, call it a "change" instead of an "improvement" and there's no implied positivity anymore. Also, this is about _suggested edits of relatively new users_. Once one has got enough reputation, they can perform all minor edits they want. It's about teaching the future power-users how to properly edit. And of course it's on a case-by-case basis, nowhere do I say I always reject minor edits.

Answer (score 6):

You're probably not rejecting too many edits, but perhaps you could instead "improve the edit" more frequently.  This would do more to improve the quality of the content than just rejecting a "marginally useful" edit.

If it is an obviously incorrect edit, I reject it outright.  If it is a partially correct edit, I weigh correcting it myself.  If it is an incremental improvement, I'll sometimes approve it, even if I think it could go further.

Comment: For the marginally useful edits that I might want to IMPROVE, I either improve them, or I skip them (because I don't have the time). I actually have a good chunk of suggestions where I don't know what to do so I just skip them.

Answer (score 4):

Anyone with suggested edits haven't been around enough to earn the 'just edit it' privilege. I think I'm right in saying it earns a bit of rep too?

But anyway, my standards are high, because *this* is the time to learn what makes a 'good' edit before they get to the point where they can do so without approval.

Comment: I wish moderators didn't only care about problems, they should look on meta and improve the site!

Comment: @avaragecoder Er, what? Moderators care about the entire site, not sure where you got this idea from.

Comment: Correct; having a suggested edit approved yields 2 reputation (limit of 1,000 reputation gained in this manner)

Answer (score -7):

I would not worry about it. I reject very few edits. Simply because most edits actually does improve the post. Even if it often is a quite small difference, it is still an improvement. An overwhelming percentage of my rejects are the tests to see if I pay attention. I've never rejected any edit because it is to trivial or because the editor did not fix everything.

Here are my current stats:

> klutt has approved 74 edit suggestions and rejected 12 edit suggestions and improved 16 edit suggestions

Sometimes I have thought "can it really be so few rejects?" Then I have slowed down and really spent time on every single review to see if they are good or bad, but every time I've come to the conclusion that mosts edits really are good. Or at least they make some improvement.

When I review "first posts" and "low quality posts" it is the exact opposite. Most of them are bad.

And maybe I should clarify a little. I do improve edits from time to time. One of the most common things is that an editor has improved the formating, and I remove stuff like "please help me". Also, I often press skip when the edit modifies code beyond indentation and such, or when facts are altered.

Comment: Then you, sir, are robo-reviewing.

Comment: @StephenLeppik I was about to answer here, but I added it in my post instead.

Comment: The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) states that edits must be substantial. Minor edits should not be Approved. One reason is that edits bump a post to the front page. Another is to prevent rep-farming by making a series of minor edits to the same post.

Comment: @StephenLeppik As stated in the accepted answer: *"You should approve if it improves the post, even if it is just a little bit. The "Too minor" rejection reason was removed for a reason."*

Comment: @klutt That answer is 2 years old and talks about the removal of a "too minor" reject reason that was removed. Now we have "no improvement whatsoever".

Comment: @klutt That answer says a bit more. It does not deny the existence of "too minor" edits, but it puts the burden on the rejecter to make a better edit instead. Which would be fair, if there weren't so many lazy editors.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Maybe you're right. Do you know any good way to compare my previous reviews to others?

Comment: @StephenLeppik Also, there's a pretty big difference between "too minor" and "no improvement whatsoever". Every edit I have approved has (unless I made a mistake) made at least some improvement, and thus "no improvement whatsoever" is not really applicable. If it only said "no improvement" I'd agree, but the word "whatsoever" really sends a strong signal.

Comment: @klutt Well, I agree that the wording of "no improvement whatsoever" is too harsh. It's [been discussed on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270583/168333).

Comment: @S.L.Barth The way I see it, I can hardly be blamed for being liberal to edit suggestions as long as that phrase persists.