# Was it OK that this edit got approved?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits, editing-help

Today I came across [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8586594) which got approved.

First of all, I agree that the corrections made was right (*rather, not harmful*), but somehow I'm not *feeling happy* with the edit getting approved.

Keeping apart the very low quality of the question itself, I do not see how that edit made the post any more relevant. The question, even at current form itself, is not a question at all, IMHO.

If I would have got the chance to review, I would have failed the review under

> **no improvement whatsoever**
>
>   This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."

(with *more stress* on the first part of the last sentence.)

I request to hear the arguments in favour/against my opinion.

---

*Note: Maybe not directly related, maybe not related at all, but I'm also surprised by the "Reviewer(s) Stats", specifically the ratio.*

Comment: While it has improved it slightly grammatically, I personally do not think it has being improved enough because it still does not read very well.

Comment: This is called "turd polishing".  No matter what anybody does to it or how stellar the edit, that question will always be a turd.  Whether that's a useful activity is not that relevant, the real problem is that it only got a single close vote after an hour in a frequently visited tag.  Not being able to eradicate these turds is the bigger issue, not in the least because there are just *way* too many of them.   All that SO users can do anymore is being careful where they step.  The question title helps btw.

Comment: @ciaran82 that is exactly my point !!! :-)

Comment: @HansPassant close vote is mine, so are the comments, but I'm (_was_) alone. :-(

Comment: Well, not completely alone, there was somebody that tried to polish.  Not yet cynical enough, probably, one has to admire his faith somewhat :)  Just DV this crap, close-voting is already entirely too much time wasted on it since that makes just more work for 4 other users in a close queue that never empties.  The roomba will clean it up.

Comment: @HansPassant Completely agree. Nevertheless, thanks to the editor for his efforts , just not up to the mark to save the post, but that's not entirely his fault, anyway. :-(

Comment: I would not approve it.Grammatical,spelling improve does not improve a bad/off-topic question. I would approve it if the question is good.

Comment: I think we are missing the point about the reviewer stats.. See guys look habitual approver (if there is a word like this) of the edits made.

Comment: @Amit Yep, thanks for reading the note. However, we cannot _solely_ count on that. :-)

Comment: The reviewer stats are dung busted, and have been for a long time. They used to be useful, no longer so. Ignore them until fixed. 6-8 of some unspecified time-unit.

Comment: I have a doubt, don't flags get disputed by edits? At least that is what I have understood from reading other posts on Meta. So in theory if someone flags the question, and then this edit gets through, wouldn't that dispute the flag?

Comment: I won't repeat any of the points already covered concisely by others, but I agree with the general consensus against this approved edit.  That said, what annoys me is that "*enter link description here*" was left unedited.  Those kinds of default texts... I dunno, call it a pet-peeve, but they make me cringe.

Comment: @HansPassant, Where did that phrase come from?

Comment: Jeff Atwood, one of the site founders, liked to use it when talking about this activity.  The idiom is old, the Mythbusters [checked if it is possible :)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiJ9fy1qSFI).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would have rejected it. It still doesn't really parse right, and doesn't seem to get to the point of the question the OP seems to be asking. Add to that, that the question itself isn't really great (even if you would formulate it properly) and you've just bumped something which really didn't deserve that.

So overall I would have rejected.

Comment: Thanks . Also, the reason to choose there is same as I think, right?

Comment: Yeah, it was bad and is still bad. The thin coat of spray lacquer doesn't change that. So no improvement whatsoever.

Answer (score 16):

While it is not applicable for questions (such as your example), turd polishing of answers can have a harmful impact to community.

Posts in the VLQ review queue are immediately removed from the queue when the answer is edited. You could have a post with 5 "Recommend" delete votes, but someone with 1 rep or an anonymous user (with the help of 3 reviewers) can block deletion simply by editing the answer.  It basically made the effort of the VLQ reviewers worthless as those recommend delete votes are gone.  And since this is done without any fanfare, no one knows it happened.

This means trying to polish that turd of an answer could potentially help keep crap on the site when it should have been deleted.