# Should edits on VLQ questions be declined?

Tags: support, review-queues, edits, low-quality-posts

I just ran into this edit request:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23977701

This question has serious problems and should be closed.

Is it OK to reject this edit on the grounds that this effort is extremely short from actually improving the question?

Comment: Reject as no improvement (I have no idea if that's sanctioned by SE, but it's a practice I've seen used, and actually used some times too). It doesn't fix the post in any significant way. Doesn't matter anyway, if the post doesn't get improved, it'll eventually get deleted along with the edit and any rep gained by the editor.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297820/was-it-ok-that-this-edit-got-approved

Comment: Through the linked question you'll find many related questions, and answers all over the place. Personally, I'm on the "let's not polish turds" camp.

Comment: Nice. I think "this edit is just polishing turd" should be an official review queue response.  :-)

Comment: I always reject edits as 'no improvement' when I see them on bad questions