# Reviewing suggested Edit: what is wrong in my case?

Tags: discussion, review-suspension

Recently I was suspended for three review decisions and specifically for this one

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31890058

I have accepted the change because I consider that correcting English is always an improvement.

Two other reviewers have rejected this change.

#### Questions

1. Why was I suspended for this action?
2. What is the correct action to do? Reject or Approve or Reject-Edit or Approve-Edit?

Comment: _One_ issue I see is setting `**` within code block. Markdown bold syntax doesn't work within code block

Comment: They broke the code in the question by adding `**` twice. I also don't like that they changed filenames to bold. Basically any action than "Looks Ok" should be fine. I would probably picked "Improve Edit" and remove the stars in the code block.

Comment: ok: the best action would be REJECT+EDIT or perhaps APPROVE+EDIT because by approving all grammar english correction are kept !

Answer (score 20):

This edit should have been rejected due to the fact that it:

- Adds incorrect asterisks to the code, making it invalid
- Incorrectly refers to "Android Studio" instead of "Android"—the question is unrelated to the Android Studio IDE
- Adds grammar errors, such as changing "in android studio" to "in the android studio"

It also does the following arguably unhelpful things, although these are more a matter of opinion:

- Makes the title unnecessarily verbose
- Adds superfluous formatting, such as "***styles.xml***"

As far as why you were suspended from reviewing, you *also* approved [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31895014), which is quite destructive.  It deletes all indentation and adds a bug by changing the code.  All of this was explained (briefly, admittedly), in [the review suspension message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sy0c.png) that you received.

Comment: I can accept the first reason but for other the decision is very subjective. And for the first reason, the valid action would be to define this change as APPROVED and take some time to remove **. For this reason simply rejecting the answer is not a good answer !!!

Comment: @schlebe - Rejecting an invalid edit is the best answer, if you are not willing, to make edits to the contribution being reviewed yourself.  **By rejecting invalid edits, the contributing user who made the bad edits, will stop making bad edits.** In summary, both of the edits that you approved, were destructive in some capacity.

Comment: Would you accept "improve edit" as a review decision for edits like the one in the question? That one specifically does a little too much wrong (>50%) for that to be a decision I would make as a reviewer, but sometimes I use "improve" then revert the few bad changes in edits that have too many good changes for me to want to repeat those.

Comment: @Laurel Yes (grudgingly), as long as it addressed all the major issues with the edit.  I'd *prefer* rejecting, for the reasons you describe, but accepting the edit while fixing the issues with it is defensible.

Comment: @schlebe Ideally, Reject and Edit to fix the few things the answer actually did fix would be ideal.  But the three points I listed are *actually making the answer worse* - and three of those is too much for me to approve the edit.  It's probably more work for a reviewer to find and undo the harmful changes they made than it would be to simply start from scratch and make the edit correctly in the first place (hence Reject and Edit).

Answer (score 8):

As an addendum to [Ryan M](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/208273/ryan-m)'s [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418501), I'd like to address the following from your question:

> I consider that correcting English is always an improvement

No, this is **not always** an improvement. The [guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303244/11407695) on suggested edits are quite clear: since there can only be [500 suggestions at a time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351728/11407695), and there is a very limited number of reviewers, suggestions are **required** to fix as many problems with the post as possible lest they risk being rejected.

How much "as many as" is a judgement call, of course, but the rule of thumb is to consider edits that omit glaring issues with the post to be rejection-worthy (if you feel educational, "reject and edit"). The reason for this is that by approving incomplete suggestions, you encourage more. Don't forget that the suggestor [earns 2 rep points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/786798) for each of the approved edits — don't underestimate the power of extrinsic motivation.

Comment: `500` that is the max queue length?

Comment: Yup, @QHarr, max length at any given point in time (I should probably link to that, thanks!)

Comment: I understand your point of view, but I regret that SO doesn't add reject's explanation that is "rejected because improvement is incomplete" !

Comment: Not my point of view, the guidelines' :) That said, yes, the review queue system is generally badly designed, barely works, and is a huge chore overall. The guidance for reviewers that SE provides is insufficient at best and misleading at worst...

Comment: I agree with your analyse.

Comment: @schlebe If an edit improves a post you should accept it. There is no rule that says you should only approve complete edits that addresses all deficits (on the contrary!), but the edit you approved also added cruft and invalid changes, which is why should have rejected.

Comment: There is no requirement that edit suggestions have to fix as many problems as possible, there is only a guideline that advices you to do so. Incomplete edits by themselves are not a reason for rejection, if you come across an edit suggestion that doesn't address all deficits you should "Improve Edit" if you have the time, or otherwise Approve.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel your advice is incorrect: "suggested edits in the queue are expected to fix all of these". One is free to ignore the community guidelines if they want to, but that's a surefire way to earn a review suspension one day.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine That is an expectation on the one performing the edit. It does not establish a requirement on the reviewer to reject "incomplete" edits. On the contrary, the expectation on reviewers has always been to either approve or improve such edit suggestions if they think the edit falls short, not to reject.

Comment: A reviewer is *supposed* to look for edits that fall short of community guidelines, @MarkRotteveel. If an edit fails to follow them, it's not a good edit. It's a judgement call at which point the number of missed issues starts to outweigh the benefits of the edit, but it's never been expected to approve incomplete edits.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine It has, see for example [Approve as too minor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor), ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site), [Am I rejecting too many edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297817/am-i-rejecting-too-many-edits)

Comment: This is not about the "too minor" reason, @MarkRotteveel. Again, if the edit misses issues (or even worse, such as in this case, introduces ones), there is a "Reject and Edit" option, see Shog9's own comment under the [change post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor#comment1003783_238039) for one example. And none of those imply that one must approve edits that forgo other issues (I'll omit the one where you are the author, if you don't mind).

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine You are reading very selectively. The "too minor" rejection reason was removed, so if an edit improves the post (without introducing problems), it should be accepted, to quote from that answer by Shog9: _"If it's really too minor, reviewers should demonstrate that by providing a not-minor edit. If the reviewer opts to build upon the edit instead of starting over from the current revision, then it isn't too minor!"_.

Comment: Hold on. You're telling me that there are around 22 million questions listed, around 18 million users (only a tiny percentage of whom have 2000+ reputation), and it is only possible to have *five hundred* pending edits on the *entire site*, **just** so we can maintain the "review queue" feature???????? "suggestions are required to fix as many problems with the post" the very concept makes my stomach turn. This is a site for programmers; we all understand how version control works, right?

Comment: Meanwhile, if the queue is such a problem, then why do we have such pedantic and slow policies for clearing it? As I've pointed out before, I even have to wait for someone else to cooperate to approve someone else's edit, even though I could just "steal" it to get it up immediately. It makes no sense at all.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it's a bandage on a bleeding wound, yeah. The system governing suggested edits (and review queues in general) is extremely poorly designed. If it was done better, the limit would not even be needed (I am in favor of it in the *current* state of affairs, though - it at least saves us from miriads of, ahem, "fixes"). It does not help that edits for tag wikis/excerpts are mixed in with "I" capitalizations.