# Why is my edit rejected, but a similar edit made 2 minutes later

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I am confused why [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8019220) is rejected. I removed a 'THANK you!' message, and because I was editing the question anyway, I decided to fix a spelling error (I've never heard of a 'back slash', google and wikipedia agree with me the word is 'backslash'). 2 minutes later, the user that rejected my edit, made a [similar edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30161720/revisions) removing the 'THANK you'.

Comment: To add insult to injury, that user didn't simply make a similar edit in your place - they *took your edit, undid the spelling change, and submitted what was left*. You can see this because the decision says "Reject and Edit" rather than simply "Reject".

Comment: The post started with a lowercase "in". For the next time, please fix those issues as well.

Comment: _"from a user with no other Suggested-Edit reviews."_ The review counters are known to be a little wacky, I believe especially so when `Reject and Edit` is used. The reviewer in question there, _also_ the reviewer in question with the OP's review, has other Suggested Edit reviews. Disregard that counter there.

Comment: @BoltClock as a side note, if you open the first link in the question, and expand it with (more), i'll see that _Milap has approved 0 edit suggestions and rejected 0 edit suggestions_. How can that be, given it is saying just above that he used "reject and edit"? is that a bug?

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ I've seen [a report](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272597/suggested-edits-showing-the-wrong-stats) of that before. That was 7 months ago thou.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Well, let's take a look:

> Milap reviewed this 1 hour ago: Reject and Edit
>   Community♦ reviewed this 1 hour ago: Reject
>   *This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.*
>   Pascal reviewed this 1 hour ago: Approve

So, Pascal approved your edit, and then Community♦ rejected it because Milap decided to reject your edit as inappropriate and do a good edit himself.
So, let's look what you did:

- You corrected the name of `\`, the one time it was used, from "back slash" (which is hard on backs) to "backslash", which is the character meant.
- You removed fluff ("Thank you", to be exact).

Milap did the latter but not the former.
So, it seems he isn't quite up to speed on typography, and he is oblivious but sure, which is worse.

In conclusion, sometimes even a good edit is rejected. While that's far less often than a bad edit getting approved, do enough edits and you'll run into it anyway.
If your edits are overall of similar or better quality (the first sentence should start with an uppercase letter, and it can be polished slightly more, not that it really *has* to), sporadic spurious rejections don't really hurt, so keep it up.

Comment: Now we have at least 40 people spent time on looking at change that should not have been made in a first place if your changes go through review queue... For 2 internet imaginary points... On other hand this question is better reading then many SO question - so overall positive impact on readers, negative impact on the site.

Comment: Reputation is serious business.

Comment: If someone does an edit and I click "approve" it will await approval from other users before taking effect (and I can't do anything at all about it meanwhile). This can be frustrating, because I could have edited it myself and it would have taken effect immediately. Due to this it's faster to reject the edit and do the edit myself instead. (Approve and improve or whatever it's called doesn't work because it complains that I didn't improve the edit enough IIRC.)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't claim to have high rep in the slightest, but my contributions to Stack Overflow's Google Apps Script, and a few other tags actually was an influencing factor in me getting hired recently as a freelance developer. You'd be surprised by [the differing views that some people have on reputation/contribution to SE in terms of employment](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/20407/109112); my current employer values public contributions ;)

Answer (score 11):

@Milap decided your edit wasn't something he wanted to encourage to be sent to the edit review queue by stating it was a good edit.

He rejected it.

Why did he reject and edit?  I can think of a few reasons.

First, the only reliable way to reject an edit without it being overridden by people who robo-review and accept everything short of obvious spam and random gibberish audits is to reject & edit.

In a sense, in the edit review queue, "reject and edit" is the super-reject option.

Second, maybe he was uncertain about `backslash` vs `back slash` as a change to the original post.  As he was unsure, he rejected it, then did the changes that he was sure of (removing the thank you), and finished up.

Third, maybe some other reason.  Maybe it wasn't Milap, it was actually a cat walking on Milap's keyboard.  Maybe the reviewer is working on edit badges, saw a mediocre edit, turned part of it into their own edit for credit, and got both a review-edit point and an edit-point.  Maybe Milap was going to make more changes, but got distracted and committed it half-finished.  Maybe Milap actually hit the wrong button.

---

The post ended up in a better state than it was before.  Possibly if your edit was accepted it would be in an even better state: but had you fixed all the issues in the post, the post would also have been in a better state.  We can't get hung up on the best of all possible edits (where all edits are perfect), for in the world, your edit would also be worthy of rejection!

In any case, the net quality of the website was increased.  Not by much in either case, but it was upward not downward.

In conclusion, sometimes a mediocre edit is rejected and replaced with another mediocre edit.

If you want to avoid your mediocre edits from being rejected, increase your reputation over the threshold and you can make mediocre edits without meaningful review until the cows come home.

Another option is to write amazing edits with great descriptions that will cow edit reviewers into accepting it verbatim.  This is less effective: even amazing edits will be rejected for no good reason (possibly involving cats, but you never can say).

Comment: Just a heads up, there's an "Improve edit" option that looks _slightly better_ on the review record. The rest of your answer isn't that bad, though it says a lot of what the other ones says.

Comment: @KevinBrown Sure.  The big difference is that Deduplicator's core message is "the edit was good, keep it up, and the result after the review was significantly worse" to my reading.  Mine is "The change was mediocre.  The difference between what you proposed the post should be and what happened was not significant.": I consider that to be an important difference: saying "good job" to someone who does merely not-horrible seems wrong.  I also tried to give more reasons for why the reviewer reject-and-edited the post than the incompetence assumption of the other answer.

Comment: I agree I should probably have corrected more and make a top class edit instead of a mediocre one. My confusion came from the fact that half my edit got rejected, indicating I should not have made the spelling correction in combination with removing fluff. Anyway, time to do more good and get those pesky 46 points. If only people up-voted my questions on SO as much as they did on meta...